# Keras Conv2D without MaxPool2D but the Output Shape is divided by 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I found two problems in the following Keras model.

Here is the full test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model=tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(15,(5,5), padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(5,5)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(5,5),padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics = [
        "accuracy"
    ]
)

model.summary()
```

Here is the output:

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_18 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 15)        390       
                                                                 
 conv2d_19 (Conv2D)          (None, 24, 24, 16)        6016      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPoolin  (None, 12, 12, 16)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_20 (Conv2D)          (None, 12, 12, 32)        12832     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPoolin  (None, 6, 6, 32)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 1152)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 10)                11530     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 30,768
Trainable params: 30,768
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Question 1:**

This layer will generate the Output Shape as "`(None, 24, 24, 16)`".

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(5,5)))
```

There is no any `tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D` between the `first` layer and the `second` layer, why does the second layer still change the output shape to `(None, 24, 24, 16)`?

It should be `(None, 28, 28, 16)` because no any `MaxPool2D` before the second layer.

**Question 2:**

Why does the `input_shape` argument in this layer can't change the model to `input_shape=(28, 28, 3)`:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(5,5),padding='same', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
```

Comment: 1 - Read here (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) on the details of how padding is calculated and how it affects the shape of your output. 2 - You can't just change the model to a different shape when the input is (12, 12, 32). `input_shape` parameter is meaningless in intermediate layers.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very helpful. The calculation method is missing in the Conv2D  doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

Your 2nd `Conv2D` layer is missing `padding=same`. It defaults to `padding=valid` therefore, the output size is `28-5+1=24`.

### Question 2

Not sure what you expected here. Sequential models can have only 1 input (which you've already defined the shape of, in the first layer). `input_shape` in the middle layers has no effect.